# How do I allow users to input their information in a stored profile through Firebase without making them log in/register?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, profile

I am creating an ios app that has a news feed in it. I don't want users to have to sign up. I want them to be able to input their profile information, and have it saved to their specific device so that it is there when they open the app back up.

Comment: Do you want to store any user info on Firebase? If not, why can't you just store everything locally, using either UserDefaults, a Plist file, or even an old fashioned text file?

Comment: If you allow a user to store data in Firebase without authenticating how would you go back and read that users data back later? i.e. How would your app know what data to read back in? Along those lines, even if you come up with a scheme to do that then the data would be publicly available and if you store email addresses it would be an instant spam list for whoever wants it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save the information about your users on firebase, maybe you can try to use the framework Core Data, so you can save and consult information like a database SQLite, you can read more about it and you can decide if you want to use it or not: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

Also you can use UserDefaults property.